# Help converting LINQ expression from C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I'm having a little trouble converting some LINQ to VB. I've taken a pass at figuring it out but I've been unsuccessful this moring thus far.

```
 var feeds = 
  from feed in feedXML.Descendants("item")
  select new
  {
    Date = DateTime.Parse(feed.Element("pubDate").Value)
                   .ToShortDateString(),
    Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
    Link = feed.Element("link").Value,
    Description = feed.Element("description").Value,
  };
```

Online code translators are not helping, and my unfamiliarly with VB LINQ is not very good. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to:

1. Use the `With` keyword when projecting into an anonymous type.
2. Prefix property names with a dot.
3. Use a line continuation depending on your version of VB.NET (not needed in VB10). A line continuation is denoted by an underscore at the end of each line.

This yields:

```
Dim feeds = From feed in feedXML.Descendants("item")
            Select New With
            {
                .Date = DateTime.Parse(feed.Element("pubDate").Value).ToShortDateString(),
                .Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
                .Link = feed.Element("link").Value,
                .Description = feed.Element("description").Value
            }
```

Comment: wow, 2 almost identical answers (and 2 identical comments), +1 each

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim feeds = From feed In feedXML.Descendants("item") _
            Select New With { _
               .Date = DateTime.Parse(feed.Element("pubDate").Value).ToShortDateString(), _
               .Title = feed.Element("title").Value, _
               .Link = feed.Element("link").Value, _
               .Description = feed.Element("description").Value, _
            }
```

Comment: wow, 2 almost identical answers (and 2 identical comments), +1 each

Comment: Wow, I was making that much harder than it needed to be. Thanks.